# isPresent() method returns false (in testing with Mockito)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the following method with JUnit tests, using Mockito:

```
@Override
public List<Adoption> search(String username, Integer id) {

    List<Adoption> emptySearchResult = new ArrayList<>();

    if(id != null && !username.equals("") ) {
        if(!this.petRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            return emptySearchResult;
        }
        if(!this.appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).isPresent()){
            return emptySearchResult;
        }
        Pet pet = this.petRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow( () -> new PetNotFoundException(id));
        AppUser user  = this.appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow( () -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username));
        return this.adoptionRepository.findAllByUserAndPet(user, pet);
    }
    else if(id != null && username.equals("")){
        if(!this.petRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            return emptySearchResult;
        }
        Pet pet = this.petRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow( () -> new PetNotFoundException(id));
        return this.adoptionRepository.findAllByPet(pet);
    }
    else if(id == null && !username.equals("")) {
        if(!this.appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).isPresent()){
            return emptySearchResult;
        }
        AppUser user  = this.appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow( () -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username));
        return this.adoptionRepository.findAllByUser(user);
    }
    else {
        return this.adoptionRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

The initialization for my tests looks like this:

```
@Mock
private AdoptionRepository adoptionRepository;

@Mock
private PetRepository petRepository;

@Mock
private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

private AdoptionServiceImpl service;

private Adoption adoption1;
private Adoption adoption2;
private Adoption adoption3;

private AppUser user;
private AppUser user2;
private Pet pet;
private Pet petAlteadyAdopted;

List<Adoption> allAdoptions = new ArrayList<>();
List<Adoption> userFilteredAdoptions = new ArrayList<>();
List<Adoption> petFilteredAdoptions = new ArrayList<>();

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    user = new AppUser("username","name","lastname","email@gmail.com","pass",ZonedDateTime.now(), Role.ROLE_USER, City.Skopje);
    user2 = new AppUser("username1","name","lastname","email@gmail.com","pass",ZonedDateTime.now(), Role.ROLE_USER, City.Skopje);

    Center center = new Center("a", City.Bitola,"url");
    pet = new Pet("p", Type.DOG,"b", Gender.FEMALE,"d",center, ZonedDateTime.now(),"url",null,false,ZonedDateTime.now());
    petAlteadyAdopted = new Pet("p", Type.DOG,"b", Gender.FEMALE,"d",center, ZonedDateTime.now(),"url",null,true,ZonedDateTime.now());

    pet.setId(0);
    petAlteadyAdopted.setId(1);
    adoption1 = new Adoption(ZonedDateTime.now(),ZonedDateTime.now(),Status.ACTIVE,user,pet);
    adoption2 = new Adoption(ZonedDateTime.now(),ZonedDateTime.now(),Status.CLOSED,user,pet);
    adoption3 = new Adoption(ZonedDateTime.now(),ZonedDateTime.now(),Status.CLOSED,user2,new Pet());

    allAdoptions.add(adoption1);
    allAdoptions.add(adoption2);
    allAdoptions.add(adoption3);

    petFilteredAdoptions.add(adoption2);
    petFilteredAdoptions.add(adoption1);

    userFilteredAdoptions.add(adoption2);
    userFilteredAdoptions.add(adoption1);

    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.findById(0)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(adoption1));
    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(adoption2));

    Mockito.when(this.petRepository.findById(0)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(pet));
    Mockito.when(this.petRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(petAlteadyAdopted));

    Mockito.when(this.appUserRepository.findByUsername("username")).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(user));
    Mockito.when(this.appUserRepository.findByUsername("username1")).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(user2));

    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(allAdoptions);
    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.findAllByPet(pet)).thenReturn(petFilteredAdoptions);
    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.findAllByUser(user)).thenReturn(userFilteredAdoptions);
    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.findAllByUserAndPet(user,pet)).thenReturn(userFilteredAdoptions);

    Mockito.when(this.adoptionRepository.save(Mockito.any(Adoption.class))).thenReturn(adoption1);

    this.service = Mockito.spy(new AdoptionServiceImpl(this.adoptionRepository, this.petRepository,this.appUserRepository));
}
```

When I run my tests, the following two tests fail:

```
@Test
public void searchTest2() { 
    List<Adoption> adoptionList = this.service.search("",0);
    Assert.assertEquals(petFilteredAdoptions,adoptionList);
}
```

and

```
@Test
public void searchTest4() { 
    List<Adoption> adoptionList = this.service.search("username",0);
    Assert.assertEquals(userFilteredAdoptions,adoptionList);
}
```

The AssertionError for the first test is:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
> Expected :[Adoption(id=null, adoptionTime=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], realLifeTime=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], status=CLOSED, user=AppUser(username=username, name=name, lastname=lastname, email=email@gmail.com, password=pass, profilePicture=null, startDate=2022-01-31T01:57:02.886098+01:00[Europe/Skopje], service=null, role=ROLE_USER, city=Skopje, worksAt=null, isAccountNonExpired=true, isAccountNonLocked=true, isCredentialsNonExpired=true, isEnabled=true), pet=Pet(id=0, name=p, age=null, breed=b, description=d, url=url, arivalDate=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], dateOfBirth=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], adopted=false, ageGroup=null, type=DOG, gender=FEMALE, savedBy=null, center=Center(id=null, address=a, url=url, city=Bitola))), Adoption(id=null, adoptionTime=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], realLifeTime=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], status=ACTIVE, user=AppUser(username=username, name=name, lastname=lastname, email=email@gmail.com, password=pass, profilePicture=null, startDate=2022-01-31T01:57:02.886098+01:00[Europe/Skopje], service=null, role=ROLE_USER, city=Skopje, worksAt=null, isAccountNonExpired=true, isAccountNonLocked=true, isCredentialsNonExpired=true, isEnabled=true), pet=Pet(id=0, name=p, age=null, breed=b, description=d, url=url, arivalDate=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], dateOfBirth=2022-01-31T01:57:02.887095400+01:00[Europe/Skopje], adopted=false, ageGroup=null, type=DOG, gender=FEMALE, savedBy=null, center=Center(id=null, address=a, url=url, city=Bitola)))]
> Actual   :[]

After debugging, I figured out that the reason for this is that in the following code snippet of the original method:

```
if(!this.petRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            return emptySearchResult;
        }
```

the isPresent() method returns false. This makes no sense to me, because in the initialization of my tests with mockito, I covered the petRepository.findById(id):

```
Mockito.when(this.petRepository.findById(0)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(pet));
```

Any ideas about what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I would say your code is wrong, you shouldn't use `isPresent` but rather just a single `oElseThrow` which will either return something or throw an exception. You ar e actually executing a query twice.

Comment: @M.Deinum but I don't need an exception to be thrown. I'm checking if it's present and returning an empty array if it's not.

Comment: Then just use `orElse`... Your code currently doesn't make sense, as 2 lines down it is downing exactly that, throwing an exception. Looks like you are trying to use optional in a a way that you shouldn't be using it. Or even better, just write a query that handles these cases instead of using all those `if` statements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see now that you've asked this question twice; this is the first one, and I've attempted to answer [your repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70926321/1426891) while I was unaware of this question. Please don't repeat your question; you may [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) to include new details, such as the WrongTypeOfReturnValue addition from your repost. Closing this question per [meta advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278510/1426891).

Comment: @JeffBowman It wasn't the same question, it was a completely different problem regarding the same code, but it's okay since I solved my issue. Thank you for your help on my other post!